# Gradle task order for creating dynamic Global List for a Copy task exclude

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

Ok, I am still having an issue and would greatly appreciate someone shedding some light on what I am obviously missing.
I thought I understood the Gradle task I wanted to accomplish, but I cannot seem to get one last bit working.

Here is what I want to do, in numbered order:

1. Create a dynamic, global 'copyExcludes' list; in one task
2. Copy entire directory tree, excluding the 'copyExcludes' list; in another task
3. Run the maven command 'mvn verify' on every directory in the file tree from the Copy task
4. Create a ZIP archive for the directory tree after all the Maven commands complete successfully.

Below is the code, I have been hacking at, and cannot get the 'copyExcludes' list, to update, BEFORE the 'copy' task executes, thus ALL modules (sub directories) are copied over, not just the few that I want.

```
/**
 * Copy all files to ${assemblyDir}, then run 'mvn verify' on each and every included module.
 * Then create an assembly ZIP
 */
def copyFromDir = rootProject.file('.')

def assemblyDir = "target/gradle_assembly"
def assemblyDestination = "target/assembly"
def assemblyName = "assembly.zip"

def List includedModules = []

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
def allModules = [
        'common',
        'spring-hello-world',
        'spring-configuration',
        'spring-advanced-configuration',
        'spring-jdbc',

        'spring-jms',
        'spring-batch',
        'spring-batch-configuration'
]

def copyExcludes = []

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

/**
 * Copy all files from root (./)
 but exclude the module sub directories that are from 'getCopyExcludes(allModules)'
 */
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {

    def cpExcludes = []

    ext {
        println "********** copyFiles ext{} **********"
        println "1 ********** (${copyExcludes.size()}) copyExcludes: '${copyExcludes}' **********"
        cpExcludes = copyExcludes
        cpExcludes = getCopyExcludes(allModules)
    }

    doFirst {
        println "********** copyFiles doFirst{} **********"
        println "2 ********** (${copyExcludes.size()}) copyExcludes: '${copyExcludes}' **********"
        cpExcludes = copyExcludes
        cpExcludes = getCopyExcludes(allModules)
        println "********** (${cpExcludes.size()}) cpExcludes: '${cpExcludes}' **********"

    }

//    doLast{

        if (file(buildDir).exists()) {
            delete "./target"
        }

        from("${copyFromDir}") {
            into '.'

            include '*'
            include '**/*' //to include contents of a folder present inside Reports directory
            include '**/*.*' //to include contents of a folder present inside Reports directory

            exclude (getCopyExcludes(allModules))

        }
        into {
            def outputDir = assemblyDir;
            outputDir
        }
//    }
}



//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//task mavenVerify() {
task mavenVerify(dependsOn:copyFiles) {

    println "\n\n********** mavenVerify **********\n"

    def moduleDir = "${assemblyDir}/code"

    doLast {

        // For each module that is to be included,
        allModules.each { module ->

        if (file("${assemblyDir}/code/${module}").exists()) {
            moduleDir = "${assemblyDir}/code/${module}"

            exec {
                args "-D${mavenRepo} -D${mavenOpt}"
                workingDir "${moduleDir}"

                def command = commandLine 'mvn', 'verify'
            }
            println "---------->  END ${moduleDir} ----------\n"
        }

        }
    }
    return "success"
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

/**
 * Create a ZIP file for the previoulsy validate code copied and verified.
 */
task assembleZip(type: Zip, dependsOn:mavenVerify){

    println "********** assembleZip **********"

    from "${assemblyDir}"
    include '*'
    include '**/*' //to include contents of a folder present inside Reports directory
    include '**/*.*' //to include contents of a folder present inside Reports directory
    archiveName "${assemblyName}"
    destinationDir(file("${assemblyDestination}"))

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//


task basic_jdbc_aop_mvc_rest << {

    println "********** basic_jdbc_aop_mvc_rest **********"

    def modulesToKeep = []

//    doFirst{
    ext {
        // Create List
        modulesToKeep.addAll(modules_basic())
        modulesToKeep.addAll(modules_jdbc())

//        println "********** (${modulesToKeep.size}) modulesToKeep: '${modulesToKeep}' **********"

//        allModules.removeAll(modulesToKeep)
//         includedModules = allModules
//        println "********** (${includedModules.size()}) allModules (pre): '${includedModules/**/}' **********"
//        copyExcludes = getCopyExcludes(allModules)
//        println "********** (${copyExcludes.size()}) copyExcludes: '${copyExcludes}' **********"
    }

//    doFirst{
//        println "********** (${allModules.size()}) allModules (pre): '${allModules}' **********"
//        println "********** (${modulesToKeep.size}) modulesToKeep: '${modulesToKeep}' **********"

//        includedModules = allModules.minus(modulesToKeep)
        allModules.removeAll(modulesToKeep)
         includedModules = allModules
        println "********** (${includedModules.size()}) allModules (pre): '${includedModules/**/}' **********"
        copyExcludes = getCopyExcludes(allModules)
//        println "********** (${copyExcludes.size()}) copyExcludes: '${copyExcludes}' **********"
//    }

}


def List getCopyExcludes(mtr) {
    def newList = mtr.collect{ "**/${it}" }

    newList.addAll('**/target',
                    '**/.git',
                    '**/*.iml',
                    '**/.idea',
                    '**/gradle', // #5
                    '**/.gradle',
    )
//    newList.addAll(modulesToRemoveExclude(mtr))
    println "********** getCopyExcludes newList (${newList.size}): '${newList}' **********"
    return newList
}


[copyFiles]*.shouldRunAfter basic_jdbc_aop_mvc_rest


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
def modules_basic(){
    return [
            // Basic
            'common',
            'spring-hello-world',
            'spring-configuration',
            'spring-advanced-configuration'
    ]

}

def modules_jdbc(){
    return [
            // JDBC
            'spring-jdbc'
    ]

}


//--- THE END ---------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing yourself with all the debug statements.  Perhaps trimming it down to the bare minimum will help you see the problem better?

For example, it's hard to see problem areas like an "into ." inside a from clause and a strange looking "def List getCopyExcludes(mtr)" function declaration.

For example, here is a similar smaller script that does what you want it to do.

```
def copyFromDir = "source/gradle_assembly"
def assemblyDir = "target/gradle_assembly"

task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    from "${copyFromDir}" 
    into "${assemblyDir}"
    exclude getCopyExcludes()
}

def getCopyExcludes() {
    // exclude these 2 log files
    return ["tomcat.log", "cargo.log"]
}
```

Perhaps from here, you can expand it out to your current version by adding each task back in one at a time while verifying it still works?  If it breaks something, you'll know what caused it.

Comment: I can start with this example, but can you tell me how I would take input from the command line, such as either calling a task that set the actual list, or a series of parameters taken in from the command line?

Comment: You can pass in parameters to the gradlew task by using -Pparam1=hello .  Inside the gradle code, you can access them via project.getProperty("param1").  Does this answer your question? :)